# cp vs. cp -r on symlinks

Tags: shell, symlink, cp

I recently experimented with the cp command, and noticed the following:
Lets assume we have a folder `foo`, containing the file `bar` and the symbolic link `l-bar`:

```
foo
|-- bar
|-- lbar -> bar
```

When copying `lbar` with the default `cp lbar copy-lbar`, we get

```
foo
|-- bar
|-- copy-lbar
|-- lbar -> bar
```

where `copy-lbar` is a regular file, containing the original content of `bar`. `copy-lbar` isn't linked in any way to `bar` or `lbar`.
When using `cp -r lbar copy-lbar-recursive` instead, we get the following:

```
foo
|-- bar
|-- copy-lbar
|-- copy-lbar-recursive -> bar
|-- lbar -> bar
```

Now, just as `lbar`, `copy-lbar-recursive` represents a link to the original `bar` file.

But why does the `-r, --recursive` option of `cp` change the way links are copied?
The `help` and `manual` of `cp` both just flag it as *"copy directories recursively"*.
What happens internally that `-r` has a different effect on a symbolic link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/cp) (but not the Debian manpage, for example), describes the behaviour as follows

> When copying from a symbolic link, cp normally follows the link only when not copying recursively or when `--link` (`-l`) is used. This default can be overridden with the `--archive` (`-a`), `-d`, `--dereference` (`-L`), `--no-dereference` (`-P`), and `-H` options.

It also writes,

> ‘**`--recursive`**’
> Copy directories recursively. By default, do not follow symbolic links in the source unless used together with the `--link` (`-l`) option [...]

> It is not portable to use -r to copy symbolic links or special files. [...]

> Also it is not portable to use -R to copy symbolic links unless you also specify -P, as POSIX allows implementations that dereference symbolic links by default.

So to answer your question directly, the behaviour is as described in order to maintain an element of default behavioural compatibility with POSIX.

Comment: not sure how it'd be about default compatibility with POSIX, since [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cp.html) doesn't seem to specify `-r`, but only `-R`, and for that, it says "it is unspecified which of `-H`, `-L`, or `-P` will be used as a default".

Comment: @ilkkachu POSIX even explains in the RATIONALE section, why `-r` cannot be used in a reliable way and why `-R` has been introduced. `cp -PR ...` is what people  should recommend in answers, since this is the portable way to use `cp`.